# printing individual element from nested array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array like below

```
attributes_array = {\"rules\":{\"Claim\":[1100,1100],\"Bookmark\":[800,800]}}
```

I am trying to print Claim & Bookmark and  used below but unable to.

first:

```
attributes_array.each do |var|
  puts var.inspect
end
```

second:

```
attributes_array.each do |var|
  var.each do |val|
    puts val
  end
end
```

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: That isn't just an array. It is at least a nested hash that included multiple arrays. Furthermore, the escaped double quotes look like this is actually part of a JSON string. Where did you get that data structure from? What does `attributes_array .class` return? What exactly is the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Refine your question

```
attributes_array = { rules: { Claim: [1100, 1100], Bookmark: [800,800] } }
```

If you want to see all values:

```
attributes_array[:rules].values_at(:Claim, :Bookmark)
#=> [[1100, 1100], [800, 800]]
```

If you want to see value of `:Claim` or `:Bookmark`:

```
attributes_array[:rules][:Claim]
#=> [1100, 1100]

attributes_array[:rules][:Bookmark]
#=> [800, 800]
```

If you want to see speciific element of `:Claim` or `:Bookmark`:

```
attributes_array[:rules][:Claim].first
#=> 1100

attributes_array[:rules][:Bookmark].last
#=> 800
```

If you want hash with only `:Claim` or `:Bookmark`:

```
attributes_array[:rules].slice(:Claim)
#=> {:Claim=>[1100, 1100]}

attributes_array[:rules].slice(:Bookmark)
#=> {:Bookmark=>[800, 800]}
```